# Upload a file on server without using Relative path

Tags: jsp, servlets, ejb

i want to upload a file on to the Server using servlet with RELATIVE path.whenever i upload a file it should be uploaded in a folder under the home dirctory of my project. i don't want use the absolute path.and that path must saved into the databse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) of the servlet API to get the actual physical path of the context root and you can save the uploaded files there.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the servlet you can find out the path to some resource that is residing within the classpath like below.

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("someFile.properties");
String pathToFile = url.getPath();
```

From the 'pathToFile' variable you can find out the root of your home directory of the project. You can then save the uploaded file to this directory. Note that if you are deploying your project as a war file this might not be possible (since you can't write into the war file). But will work always if you deploy it in exploded manner.

if pathToFile=C:/someFolder/yourProject/WEB-INF/classes/someFile.properties. you can deduce that your home dir is C:/someFolder/yourProject because /WEB-INF/classes/someFile.properties part will be the same always